# How to make definitions and equations follow the section numbers?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I'm writing a paper, which roughly looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\section{My Section}

\subsection{My Subsection}

\begin{defn}
My definition: 
\begin{equation}
 Y^2 + X^3 = 0,
\end{equation}
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

So basically, the definition is displayed as Definition 1, whereas it is written inside subsection 2.1, and hence I want the definition to be written as Definition 2.1.1. Also the equation is denoted as (1), whereas I want it to be denoted as (2.1), since it is the first equation of section 2. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Usually statements are numbered just within sections: are you sure every statement is in a subsection?

Comment: What if the definition is inside section 2, but before subsection 2.1 has started?

Comment: My question was: how do you *want* them to be numbered in that case?

Comment: @egreg Since, all my definitions are inside subsections, this is not a concern for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is for an article unusual demand. however, it can be establish with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[subsection]% <--- for definitions
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection} % <--- for equations

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\section{My Section}
\subsection{My Subsection}

\begin{defn}
My definition:
\begin{equation}
 Y^2 + X^3 = 0,
\end{equation}
\end{defn}
\subsection{My Subsection}

\begin{defn}
My definition:
\begin{equation}
 Y^2 + X^3 = 0,
\end{equation}
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

[image]